Fantastic Voyage-likish anime/cartoon series
I am trying to remember a name of the animated series with the plot similiar to the Fantastic Voyage — a team of scientists fighting viruses by injecting themselves into a human body in a tiny ship.
I think it was an anime actually, though I might be mistaken. But I remember that every episode had a new virus and scientists had to find a new way to destroy it. At some point even one of the scientists got sick.
Looked through all the first three pages of Google for the match — no luck. It's definitely not the Fantastic Voyage series and not Osmosis Jones.

Welcome! To help us out, could you add any information about when you saw this, what the animation style was... anything specific you can remember about the characters. Any small details may help us help you.

Did a little more research — and turns out it is an anime called Wonder Beat Scramble.
Really not sure if foreign audiences are familiar with it — but it was showing in Russia at the beginning of the 90s and was pretty popular as much as everything foreign showing on the TV at that time.

If this is the correct answer, could you "accept" it, so it is closed off on the site. Thank you.

Sure, couldn't do that for two days, and then forgot about it.

maybe you mean Once Upon a Time... Life 


To help your answer, please explain what plot points in this show match the description in the question.
